# Sulu CMS: Is it possible to set custom http-header information for pdf files?

Tags: symfony, caddy, sulu

We would like to prevent pdf files from beeing indexed in our sulu 1.6 website. Apparently this works best, if pdf files have also a `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` attached to them.

Is there a way to configure or easily add additional http headers in sulu?

Thx a lot!

Comment: You talk about the response of the download action?

Comment: Yes, when the crawler is downloading the PDF via the link on the site to index it as well.

Comment: There is currently no way to automize this - but with a symfony event response-listener this should be quite easy to achieve https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-response

Answer (score 4):

We found, that also architecture wise (seperation of concern) it will be better to solve this on the webserver level.

In our caddy:

```
header *.pdf {
  X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
}
```

I also like it way better not to hijack sulu/symfony for this.

**Update Feb/2020**
Actually it turned out, that our webserver caddy is not as straight foreward as the above assumption. Caddy 2 can probably do it, but is not out jet.

We will investigate also a bit, weather we could upload pdf files to a specific folder instead of the dynamic delivery atm.